# ThreadPoolExecutor - BlockingQueue with priority and FIFO

Tags: java, queue, threadpoolexecutor

I am developing a queue-based application using Java.

I would like to use a ThreadPoolExecutor with blocking queue. However, the blocking queue need to be in priority, then (First In First Out) FIFO manner.

Priority
1=highest ,2=lowest

For example:

Value input in sequence:

```
1. aaaa, 2
2. bbbb, 2
3. cccc, 1
4. dddd, 2
5. eeee, 1
```

Expected value output in sequence:

```
1. cccc
2. eeee
3. aaaa
4. bbbb
5. dddd
```

Can I know is there any BlockingQueue allow me to do that?

Comment: Use LinkedBlockingQueue . You can check here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

Comment: How about `BlockingDeque` ?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue`

Comment: Dear, vinay Hegde, I think LinkedBlockingQueue can be sorted by priority, FIFO? Because I just know that it is withdraw in FIFO manner.

Comment: Dear MapReduce, BlockingDeque can be poll based on sorting order of priority, FIFO? It need to have both criteria to sort

Comment: Dear Kartik, I saw some info on PriorityBlockingQueue.
Do you means to use both FIFOEntry and priority in the compareTo method?